# How to download a webpage (mhtml format) using urllib in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, urllib

How can we save the webpage including the content in it, so that it is viewable offline, using urllib in python language? Currently I am using the following code:

```
import urllib.request 

driver.webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.yahoo.com", C:\\Users\\karanjuneja\\Downloads\\kj\\yahoo.mhtml")
```

This works and strores an mhtml version of the webpage in the folder, but when you open the file, you will only find the codes written and not the page how it appears online. Do we need to make changes to the code?
Also, is there an alternate way of saving the webpage in MHTML format with all the content as it appears online, and not just the source.Any suggestions? 
Thanks Karan

Comment: You have to tell your OS that a file with the extension  `.mhtml` is actually an HTML file. (`.mhtml` is an unusual extension for HTML files.) Or, better, use a standard extension, such as `.htm` or `.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this site might help you~
[Create an MHTML archive](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-an-mhtml-archive.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, it indeed helped me and made things simple